# Cocoapods Library bitcode - preventing to launch on phone

Tags: ios, cocoapods, bitcode

> ~ does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.

I am trying to compile my project and launch it on my phone (iPhone 6) but it throws the above error for all my cocoapods.  It launches fine in the emulator (iphone 8).  I need all the bitcodes to be turned off too which they are.

```
> post_install do |installer|   installer.pods_project.targets.each do
> |target|
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>       config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
>     end   end end
```

Comment: And is it turned off on your actual application?

Comment: It is not, that seemed to fix it.  I wasn't able to view the bitcode field before.  I had to add `fembed-bitcode` to the main project then remove it for it to appear..? Weird.